# Collect "controversial" posts of a subbredit

Tags: python, api, reddit, praw

I am trying to collect all posts from the "controversial" listing of a subbredit.

I tried with the Reddit API but there is a limit on how many post you can collect.

Then using PushiftAPI i can retrieve a big amount of posts but I can't find a way to collect from controversial listing.

Is there a way to collect controversial posts?

Comment: And what exactly defines a "controversial post"?

Comment: I dont know exactly how reddit defines a "controversial post". I think has something to do with the upvotes and downvotes. But there is a list that groups controversial posts. For example https://www.reddit.com/r/Coronavirus/controversial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PRAW gives a way to get controversial streams and you can specify the time period as well.

[From the docs](https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/models/subreddit.html?highlight=controversial#praw.models.Subreddit.controversial)

> This method can be used like:
>
> ```
> reddit.domain("imgur.com").controversial("week")
> reddit.multireddit("samuraisam", "programming").controversial("day")
> reddit.redditor("spez").controversial("month")
> reddit.redditor("spez").comments.controversial("year")
> reddit.redditor("spez").submissions.controversial("all")
> reddit.subreddit("all").controversial("hour")
> ```

I am not familiar with PushiftAPI but hopefully this helps.